# OBIEE time dimension against Essbase

Tags: obiee, essbase

Good morning! I'm connecting to an Essbase cube that has a Years dimension (FY16,FY17,etc) and a Period dimension (YearTotal, Quarters, Months). Is there any way to make a time dimension out of these two separate dimensions? I want to be able to use time series functions in some analyses. Thanks!

edit: We're using OBIEE 11g 11.1.1.7.151020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If your cube is designed that way then there's no way of logically wrangling it into shape.

Common issue with many Essbase cubes designed like that when you're trying to utilize them in an analytical way.

Comment: Thanks Christian! It's not what I was hoping, but at least I have an answer I can go back to my team with.

Comment: Sorry. Using things in Essbase and/or SmartView just isn't the same as putting a visualization tool on top of it.

Comment: When we used things from Essbase at our company, we had ETL processes to flatten data into tables. That was the only way.

Comment: Yeah that's one way. But personally I prefer cubes with fully modeled time dimensons.